# How to solve AssertionError in Selenium Python?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, assert

I am currently working on a project in `Selenium` in `Python` and I am getting `AssertionError` when I put a specific parametrised value `6.00` in the parentheses.

**Test.py**

```
Class Test:

def test_voidnewcard(self):  
    np.createReqNewCard(expected_price= 6.00)
```

**NewCard.py**

```
Class NewCard:

def createReqNewCard(self, expected_price):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.jobOrder_xpath).send_keys(self.jobReqNewCard)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.excelButton_xpath).send_keys(self.excpath)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.topup_textbox_xpath).send_keys("1")
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.calculateAmount_xpath).click()
        subTotalAmt =  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[4]/div[1]").text
        totalCalAmt =  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/label[1]").text.replace("Total amount: $", "")
        assert subTotalAmt == totalCalAmt == expected_price, "Price mismatch! Expected price is %s, subtotal is %s, total price is %s" % (round(expected_price,2), subTotalAmt, totalCalAmt)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.buttonSubmit_xpath).click()
        time.sleep(8)
```

**Error StackTrace(If I put `6.00` as the parametrised value**

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 329, in run
    testMethod()
  File "C:\Users\lukegoh\Desktop\Python Projects\SoftwareAutomationTesting\testCases\AutoTest.py", line 77, in test_voidnewcard
    np.createReqNewCard(expected_price= 6.00)
  File "C:\Users\lukegoh\Desktop\Python Projects\SoftwareAutomationTesting\newCard\NewCard.py", line 29, in createReqNewCard
    assert subTotalAmt == totalCalAmt == expected_price, "Price mismatch! Expected price is %s, subtotal is %s, total price is %s" % (round(expected_price,2), subTotalAmt, totalCalAmt)
AssertionError: Price mismatch! Expected price is 6.0, subtotal is 6.00, total price is Total Amount: $6.00
```

**Error StackTrace(If I put `"6.00"` as the parametrised value)**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 329, in run
    testMethod()
  File "C:\Users\lukegoh\Desktop\Python Projects\SoftwareAutomationTesting\testCases\AutoTest.py", line 77, in test_voidnewcard
    np.createReqNewCard(expected_price='6.00')
  File "C:\Users\lukegoh\Desktop\Python Projects\SoftwareAutomationTesting\newCard\NewCard.py", line 29, in createReqNewCard
    assert subTotalAmt == totalCalAmt == expected_price, "Price mismatch! Expected price is %s, subtotal is %s, total price is %s" % (expected_price, subTotalAmt, totalCalAmt)
AssertionError: Price mismatch! Expected price is 6.00, subtotal is 6.00, total price is Total Amount: $6.00
```

And if I parse `subTotalAmt` and `calculateTotalAmt` into `float` like here,

**NewCard.py**

```
   subTotalAmt =  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[4]/div[1]").text
        totalCalAmt =  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Total Amount: $6.00')]").text.replace('Total amount: $6.00', '')
        assert float(subTotalAmt) == float(totalCalAmt) == expected_price, "Price mismatch! Expected price is %s, subtotal is %s, total price is %s" % (expected_price, subTotalAmt, totalCalAmt)
```

I will get this,

**Error StackTrace**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 329, in run
    testMethod()
  File "C:\Users\lukegoh\Desktop\Python Projects\SoftwareAutomationTesting\testCases\AutoTest.py", line 77, in test_voidnewcard
    np.createReqNewCard(expected_price=6.00)
  File "C:\Users\lukegoh\Desktop\Python Projects\SoftwareAutomationTesting\newCard\NewCard.py", line 29, in createReqNewCard
    assert float(subTotalAmt) == float(totalCalAmt) == expected_price, "Price mismatch! Expected price is %s, subtotal is %s, total price is %s" % (expected_price, subTotalAmt, totalCalAmt)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: Total Amount: $6.00
```

Can someone solve this issue? I just can't seem to diagnose this problem

Comment: Can somebody solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your text has a special character so you cannot convert to `float`

see the error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: Total Amount: $6.00
```

so the value of subtotalamt is

```
Total Amount: $6.00
```

use

```
float(subTotalAmt.split('$')[1])
```

this get only the number part

Note: This will check only the amount

Comment: actually it's not `subTotalAmt`. It should be `calculateTotalAmt` because it returns `Total Amount: $6.00` everytime I get error

Comment: Thanks brother! Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

`totalCalAmt` and `subTotalAmt` are strings.
Comparing strings with numbers will rely on Python's choice in type casting.

I would suggest parsing these two strings into numbers and then comparing them with `expected_price`.

Comment: You mean casting isit?

Comment: Yes, you can simply cast it, after you clean up any non-numerical character.